# windows-7 x86 to x64 upgrade

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, upgrade, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When reinstalling Windows 7, does the language, version, architecture (64-bit or 32-bit) or source (OEM, retail, or MSDN) matter?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/when-reinstalling-windows-7-does-the-language-version-architecture-64-bit-or)

is it possible to update my system from windows 7 x86 to x64 without losing data ? cpu architecture is 32bit but I have 4g ram, so to unseal the ram, I have to go with x64.

Comment: Will Win 7 x64 run on a 32-bit processor?

Comment: @frustrated - you would be hard pressed to find a 32 bit processor in a wintel machine today.

Comment: No, it won't. You need a 64bits CPU (and probably a new mainboard supporting 64bits CPU and probably new RAM and/or HDD as well when the new mainboard doesn't support the current RAM/HDD interface).

Answer (score 3):

> is it possible to update my system from windows 7 x86 to x64 without losing data ?

If you mean by inplace-upgrade, no.

If you mean by backing up data (carbonite?) and reformatting the drive, then yes.

However, will your system run amd64 Windows?

Answer (score 1):

If your CPU architecture is 32-bit, you cannot run 64-bit windows.

What make and model is your CPU?

Answer (score 1):

If CPU architecture is not 64-bit, you cannot upgrade to 64-bit version of Windows. 64-bit Windows require 64-bit instructions that are not present on 32-bit CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what processor ar architecture you have, you can not upgrade from a 32bit Windows OS to a 64bit Windows OS. You'll need to perform a clean install as long as your hardware supports 64bit, which it almost most certainly does (as others have stated).